# Table Pagination prev and next button error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I have implemented the table pagination using `react-bootstrap-table-next and react-bootstrap-table2-paginator`.
It works, but pagination should display like prevbutton, pagenum, nextbutton as it shows.

If the pagenum is `1`, on nextbutton click, it should show pagenum as 2

If the pagenum is `2`, on prevbutton click, it should show pagenum as 1

If there is no data in pagenum3 then in page 2 disable the nextbutton click.

i.e on prevbutton and nextbutton click pagenum should reflect. 
on clicking nextbutton if its no data, then disable the next button.

How to achieve this
I have shared the code in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-bhabha-jhrqm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: do you try `console.log(this.state.page)` and check that is it incremented by `1`?
If yes, I think it somewhere your code continuously set your page to 1.
Is this page helpful to you? https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/pagination-props.html#paginationnextpagetext-any

Comment: after I tested, I clicked '>' the `page` goes from `1` to `1`, however I click `<` forward, it increment by 1 from `1` to `2`

Comment: Is this page solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61789032/next-page-and-previous-page-not-working-in-react-bootstrap-table2-paginator